# How to adjust scroll bars?

Tags: javascript, extjs, scrollbar, extjs5

I have a main panel with layout vbox and it has two items. First item is a panel and second one a grid panel.

```
     var main= new Panel({
autoScroll :false,
                    title:'Information',
                    layout: {
                       type: 'vbox'
                    },
                    header: {
                       titleAlign: 'center'
                    },
                    items : [pnlFirst,gridDetails]
                 });

    var gridDetais = new Ext.grid.Panel({
                     minHeight : 200,
                     border : true,
autoScroll :true,
                     store: store,
                     width : '100%',
                     tbar :Tbar,
                     columns: columns                   
                        ],               
                 });


    var pnlFirst = new Panel({
                header :false,
                layout: {
                   type: 'vbox'
                },
                items : [panel1,panel2,panel3,panel4,panel5,panel6,panel7],
             });
```

if grid has a lot of records scroll is enable auto on all page. But i want to enable scrolling only on my grid panel.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question. It is a very simple fault by me. Grid heigth grows because data is too big. I add this config to my grid:

```
maxHeight : 500
```

Then scroll appeared.

Thanks for responding.